# Create new record based upon the presence of a record with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, model-associations, conditional-associations

I've got a rails app that has two models: `address` and `delivery`, where `address has_many :deliveries` and `delivery belongs_to :address`.

I'm attempting to create a means by which a single POST request can search to find a matching `address` in the addresses table using parameters provided in the request, if a match is found create a new `delivery`.   If no address is found, then error the request.

Here's what I have so far (not functional, but hoping I'm close(ish)):

**Controller**

```
   class DeliveriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :confirm_address, only: %i[ create edit update ]
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new {|c| c.request.format.json? }
  

def index
  render json: Delivery.all 
end


def create
  # Delivery.address_id = Address.find_by(numeric: params[:numeric], street_name: params[:street])

  # @address_of_delivery = Delivery.includes(:address).where(numeric: params[:numeric], street_name: params[:street_name], city: params[:city], state: params[:state], zip: params[:zip])

  delivery = Delivery.new(delivery_params)
  # @confirmed_address.id = self.address_id

  puts 'putting'
  # puts @address_of_delivery
  
  if delivery.save
    render json: {status: 'Awesome!', data: delivery}, status: :ok
  else
    render json: {status: 'Boo!', data: delivery.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end 

private

  def delivery_params
    params.permit(:company, :numeric, :street_name, :city, :state, :zip)
  end



  def confirm_address
    @confirmed_address = Address.find_by(numeric: params[:numeric], street_name: params[:street_name], city: params[:city], state: params[:state], zip: params[:zip])
      
      if @confirmed_address.present? 
        puts "found one!"
      else
        puts "NO DICE"
        # self.address_id = confirmed_address.id
  end
  end
```

As you can see from the controller, I've attempted several paths including using `includes` and `join`(not included in snippet), as well as trying to just hard code it.

Also tried to solve through the model, but had trouble accessing the params from the POST request:

```
class Delivery < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :address

    # accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
    attribute :numeric
    attribute :street_name
    attribute :city
    attribute :state 
    attribute :zip

    before_validation :find_associated_address

def find_associated_address
    Address.find_by(numeric: params[:numeric], street_name: params[:street])
    puts 'working in model'
end

end
```

Copy of the POST request for clarity:

```
Started POST "/deliveries" for ::1 at 2021-11-20 22:52:00 -0600
Processing by DeliveriesController#create as */*
Parameters: {"company"=>"slowcart", "numeric"=>"123", "street_name"=>"Any Street", "city"=>"NYC", "state"=>"NY", "zip"=>"010101"}
```

I'm almost certainly making a stupid mistake, but can't find the right means to do what I want to do in the docs/broader web.  Rails 6 application, btw.

Comment: You should probably take a little timeout and think this feature through a bit more. What happens if the delivery was from a year ago and is already delivered? What happens if there is a delivery for another person but with a identical address?

Comment: I believe this meets the business logic I had intended - addresses can have infinite deliveries, but no deliveries can be created unless it's for an address that previously existed in the system.  Addresses are created through separate logic.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you're properly ensuring that the address is the correct one before creating the record. You should at least add a "feedback step" where you display what you have found before creating the record.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a match in addresses table, why not just use:

```
Address.where(numeric: params[:numeric], street_name: params[:street_name], city: params[:city], state: params[:state], zip: params[:zip])
```

instead of:

```
Delivery.includes(:address).where(numeric: params[:numeric], street_name: params[:street_name], city: params[:city], state: params[:state], zip: params[:zip])
```

Also note that if you use where it returns an array. You might want to check if count is > 0 to see if there's a match

Comment: Finding addresses just fine using the `Address.where` suggestion, but falling down on the association.  Need to insert the `id` of `address` into the `address_id` field on `delivery` as well.

Comment: Then add delivery.addess_id = @address_of_delivery.id